# MongoDB Compass export just collection fields in schema

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema, mongodb-compass

Basically what I want is to export my collections field into JSON. I just need to get the all the fields the collection has and their type if possible. Now I get too much information. I do not need the probability of the fields, the uniqueness etc..

Is there a way to simply export the structure of my collections?

Thank you.

Comment: You need `mongoexport` not Mongo Compass in this case.

Comment: Is that another tool similar to compass? Could you please link it?

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATED #1

Okay, as far as I understand now, you'll need to extract schema from the whole database, but the problem here, that Schema in mongo build from first 1000 documents with [`$sample` aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/). So it's not an easy task to receive Schema from the whole collection since the DB needs to analyze each document in the collection. Which is possible via `aggregation` query with `cursor` option (and `.eachAsync method if you are using mongoose)

---

This tip is for extracting collection only:

You don't need to use `Share Schema as JSON` in Compass, instead, you should export your collection to JSON via MongoCompass, it's true and can be achieved via this option:
[image]

(But you'll need to extract every collection one by one)

But Mongo Compass isn't the correct way to export collection. You should use [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/) in this case. It's a CLI utility that is mentioned for exporting and backup collections.
And extract values via `mongoimport`

Comment: Hey Alex, Thank you for your answer. Maybe I was not clear enough. What I want is basically to receive the structure of my Collection. I do not need the values of every item. But the type would be great. Is that somehow doable?

Comment: Oh, sorry I was afk, yes, it's achievable too with compass, but it's a bit harder than that. I'll edit my answer, so please check in a two mins or so. @Marius